# Sed prepend when searching for colon

Tags: regex, sed

I need to search for each instance of a colon ":" and then prepend a string to the word before that colon.

Example:

**some data here word:number**

Desired outcome:

**some data here prepend_word:number**

I've tried:

```
 sed "s/:/s/^/prepend_/g"
```

This adds prepend_ to the beginning of the line: **prepend_some data here word:number**

```
sed "s/:/prepend_&/g"
```

this adds prepend_ right before the colon: **some data here wordprepend_:number**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
sed 's/[^[:space:]]*:/prepend_&/g'
```

The `[^[:space:]]*:` pattern searches for 0 or more non-whitespace chars and a `:` after them, and the `prepend_&` replacement pattern will replace the match with itself (see `&`) and insert `prepend_` before it.

See an [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/kbbn5I):

```
sed 's/[^[:space:]]*:/prepend_&/g' <<< "some data here word:number more:here"
```

Output: `some data here prepend_word:number prepend_more:here`.